# Make notification bar transparent enough to see links/search underneath

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

A [prominent blogger](http://andrewgelman.com/2011/12/crossvalidated-a-place-to-post-your-statistics-questions/#comment-69746) made a post today giving our site a plug. The poster initially made a comment that he could not find the search bar, and it was later determined that the opaque notification bar that tells new users to visit the FAQ obstructed all the links and the search bar in the regular header of the site.

Would it be possible to make the header bar at least transparent enough to see that *some things* exist underneath it, which would hopefully prompt the otherwise too busy to close the notification bar to get to those links (especially since the notification does not leave the browser until it is closed)? I assume this is possible, as it appears the Photography site has a semi-transparent header (see the [screen shot in this meta so question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96951/150339)).

Below is the screen shot the original blogger posted:

[image]

I realize the [notification bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notification-bar) is a contentious issue, and that [some have requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43539/150339) it be made more prominent. I post this here though as it seems to vary from site to site, and so this may only be an issue with our particular color choices. I don't think it is a big issue, and I see value in prodding users to check out the FAQ, but I think making the notification bar semi-transparent is a reasonable compromise.

Comment: I also see when I visit the comp sci site and getting the banner, the header links/search box are pushed down below the banner (so still visible). I don't know if this is browser specific though (using Chrome). If it isn't browser specific though, that would be a reasonable solution as well.

Comment: This will be fixed in the next build (after midnight tonight EST)

Comment: Also, this is no longer an issue, as we don't use the redbar thingadongdong anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Jin stated in the comments above, this was recently fixed. Instead of the transparent bar though, the whole page is just shifted downwards (see screenshot below).

[image]

Thank you to @Jin for being prompt!